# Add a custom font in Qt

Tags: qt, fonts

There's anyway to add a custom font (Such as Console Font) to Qt? How? And how do we set it to a Text Editor (QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit, etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Qt uses your window system as a font provider. You can find out all the fonts available by using the [QFontDatabase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html) class. Anyway, it is possible to add a specific custom font for your application to use using [QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont) from C++ (available under X11 only if fontconfig is available) or using the [FontLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-fontloader.html) component in QML.

For QTextEdit you can use [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#setCurrentFont) and for QPlainTextEdit you might try the font property.